# Запуск Python скрипта при выходе компьютера из сна

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Как запускать простой Python скрипт на Windows 8, когда компьютер выходит из режима сна?

Comment: В планировщике пробовал искать триггер по поводу сна?

Comment: @donRumata Пытался привязать запуск скрипта при выполнении другого события. Но скрипт так и не запустился.

Comment: А путь к шеллу "C:\Program Files\Python\Python.exe" (не знаю как точно) указывал? Или только путь к самому скрипту?

Comment: @donRumata, только к скрипту

Comment: К интерпретатору полный путь воткни. Мой коллега так с VBS монался - тоже не запускался.